# Numpy array update command explanation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How is this operation called technically and what other functionalities does it allow for:

`Z[1:-1,1:-1][birth|survive]=1`. Where `Z` is a `4x4` array and birth and survive are same size Boolean arrays. I understand what this code does, but would like to know how is this operation called and what else can I do with it (talking about this latter part `[birth|survive]`).

Comment: When you use double indexing on the left side, make sure the 1st one produces a `view`, not a `copy`.  The boolean index works only if it is immediately before the `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipe `|` is the [`bitwise or` operator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html)). Therefore, `birth|survive` is the equivalent to `np.bitwise_or(birth, survive)`. Presumably `birth` and `survive` are boolean arrays, so the output is a boolean array with the straightforward `or` behavior:

```
a = np.array([True, True, False, False])
b = np.array([True, False, False, True])
a|b
# array([ True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

For integers, each bit is considered and an integer array is returned where for each digit in the binary representation has been `or`'ed. There is a better explanation on its behavior and some examples at the [documentation page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html)).

---

Once you've created the boolean array from `birth|survive`, you are using it to do a [boolean index](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) into the `Z` array. Most simply, this can be shown with:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([True, False, True])
a[b] # the elements of a where b is True
# array([1, 3])
```

Since it's on the left side of the assignment `=`, python will assign the value `1` to every point in `Z` where `birth` or `survive` is True:

```
a[b] = 99
a
# array([99,  2, 99])
```